# How to make such tables look better?

Tags: tables

[image]

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\tiny
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.41\textwidth}
            %\centering
            \makeatletter\def\@captype{table}\makeatother\caption{The factor V.}
            %\begin{tabular}{p{0.54cm}p{0.54cm}p{0.54cm}p{0.54cm}}
            \begin{tabular}{cccc}
\hline
k1&k2&k3&k4 \\ \hline
2.283 &0.656 &0.990 &-0.404 \\
0.577 &-0.080 &0.739 &2.040 \\
-0.102 &2.023 &0.610 &-0.258 \\
0.000 &0.002 &-0.004 &0.001 \\
1.496 &1.009 &-0.445 &1.346 \\
-0.324 &1.628 &1.749 &1.095 \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}
        \hspace{-.45in}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.63\textwidth}
        %\centering
        \makeatletter\def\@captype{table}\makeatother\caption{The factor Q.}
            \begin{tabular}{p{0.55cm}p{0.68cm}p{0.68cm}p{0.68cm}p{0.55cm}p{0.68cm}p{0.68cm}p{0.68cm}}
         %\begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
\hline
f1 &  f2 & f3 & f4 & f5 & f6 & f7 & f8 \\ \hline
1.627 &0.467 &0.185 &0.643 &0.191 &1.691 &-0.542 &-0.916 \\
1.586 &-0.223 &0.861 &0.259 &0.462 &0.388 &1.030 &1.649 \\
0.819 &1.405 &-0.557 &0.756 &0.166 &-0.210 &0.426 &1.093 \\
1.035 &0.859 &0.137 &-0.313 &2.466 &-0.165 &0.092 &0.013 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}
```

Comment: Hi ! Could you put some images of what you would like ?

Comment: Booktabs for horizontal lines and siunitx to align the numbers might help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Should your table stay where you put it (I mean the one at the top and the other side by side)?

Comment: Could you please also make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. Does your document contain any setting that change the margins or the font size? If so, please  also add them to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you prefer one of the following suggestions using `booktabs` and `siunitx`. Additional assumption: You don't want your tables to float, which is why I kept the `minipage`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}


\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\captionsetup{type=table}
\caption{The factor V.}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{S[table-format=-1.4]}}
\toprule
{k1} & {k2} & {k3} & {k4} \\ \midrule
2.283 &0.656 &0.990 &-0.404 \\
0.577 &-0.080 &0.739 &2.040 \\
-0.102 &2.023 &0.610 &-0.258 \\
0.000 &0.002 &-0.004 &0.001 \\
1.496 &1.009 &-0.445 &1.346 \\
-0.324 &1.628 &1.749 &1.095 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\caption{The factor Q.}
\begin{tabular}{*{8}{S[table-format=-1.4]}}

\toprule
{f1} & {f2} & {f3} & {f4} & {f5} & {f6} & {f7} & {f8} \\ \midrule
1.627 &0.467 &0.185 &0.643 &0.191 &1.691 &-0.542 &-0.916 \\
1.586 &-0.223 &0.861 &0.259 &0.462 &0.388 &1.030 &1.649 \\
0.819 &1.405 &-0.557 &0.756 &0.166 &-0.210 &0.426 &1.093 \\
1.035 &0.859 &0.137 &-0.313 &2.466 &-0.165 &0.092 &0.013 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}


\vspace{2cm}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\captionsetup{type=table}
\caption{The factor V.}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{S[table-format=-1.4]}}
\toprule
{k1} & {k2} & {k3} & {k4} \\ \midrule
2.283 &0.656 &0.990 &-0.404 \\
0.577 &-0.080 &0.739 &2.040 \\
-0.102 &2.023 &0.610 &-0.258 \\
0.000 &0.002 &-0.004 &0.001 \\
1.496 &1.009 &-0.445 &1.346 \\
-0.324 &1.628 &1.749 &1.095 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \captionsetup{type=table}
\caption{The factor Q.}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.4]*{3}{S[table-format=-1.4]}}

\toprule
{f1}  & {f2}  & {f3}  & {f4}  \\ \midrule
1.627 &0.467  &0.185  &0.643  \\
1.586 &-0.223 &0.861  &0.259  \\
0.819 &1.405  &-0.557 &0.756  \\
1.035 &0.859  &0.137  &-0.313 \\ \midrule
 {f5} & {f6} & {f7} & {f8} \\ \midrule
0.191 &1.691 &-0.542 &-0.916\\
0.462 &0.388 &1.030 &1.649 \\
0.166 &-0.210 &0.426 &1.093 \\
2.466 &-0.165 &0.092 &0.013 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```